# HIVE DB on How to do Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, hive

I am new to HIVE and would like to understand how to test  data in one table exploded to another table correctly? Any assistance towards this is appreciated thank you

Comment: `concat_ws(',',sort_array(array)) as str1`  vs  `concat_ws(',',sort_array(collect_list(exploded_element))) str2 ,,,group by key` do full join of subqueries on key  and str and filter where not equal

Comment: Thx will try @leftjoin